# SQL - find two consecutive rows for the same ID

Tags: sql, db2

We have table like this:

```
ID  PERSON  GROUP  ASSIGNEDGROUP  CHANGEDATE
1   null    GROUP1 GROUP1         01.01.2014
1   NAME1   null   GROUP1         02.01.2014
1   null    GROUP2 GROUP2         03.01.2014
2   null    GROUP1 GROUP1         04.01.2014
2   NAME1   null   GROUP1         05.01.2014
2   null    GROUP2 GROUP2         06.01.2014
2   null    GROUP3 GROUP3         07.01.2014
```

We would like to find two consecutive rows where PERSON field will have value null for the same ID and based on the date field. (if PERSON field is null then GROUP field has value and vice verse)

So for this example only last two rows should be listed because they are for the same ID and dates between them are consecutive

```
2   null    GROUP2 GROUP2         06.01.2014
2   null    GROUP3 GROUP3         07.01.2014
```

I am trying to write some SQL syntax but really do not know how to start, this probably is some complex expression. I suppose first thing to do is to get two consecutive rows based on dates and on them to check if PERSON is null.

Thank you in advance

Comment: regarding to CHANGEDATE field but for the same ID

Comment: What if three consecutive dates?

Comment: Hi jarlh there will not be three consecutive dates we do not have such examples in our table

Comment: And how do you prevent three consecutive dates?

Comment: that is done by the system and application above this database, system behavior do not be worried about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good place to use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(person) over (partition by id order by changedate) as person_prev,
             lead(person) over (partition by id order by changedate) as person_next
      from table t
     ) t
where person is null and
      (person_prev is null or person_next is null);
```

EDIT:

The above doesn't quite work because `NULL` will be returned for the first or last row for each `id`.  Ooops.  Here is one fix:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(person) over (partition by id order by changedate) as person_prev,
             lead(person) over (partition by id order by changedate) as person_next,
             lag(id) over (partition by id order by changedate) as id_prev,
             lead(id) over (partition by id order by changedate) as id_next
      from table t
     ) t
where person is null and
      ((person_prev is null and id_prev is not null) or
       (person_next is null and id_next is not null)
      );
```

EDIT II;

How about looking for two groups that are not-null?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(group) over (partition by id order by changedate) as group_prev,
             lead(group) over (partition by id order by changedate) as group_next
      from table t
     ) t
where group is not null and
      (group_prev is not null or group_next is not null);
```

Note:  `group` is a very bad name for a column, because it is a SQL reserved word.

Comment: Hi Gordon  this works but not completely. This is result for one ID from table: 8403 null NOC NOC 2015-05-05 15:05 8403 null NOC NOC 2015-05-05 15:40

Comment: but real data is: 8403 null NOC NOC 2015-05-05 15:05  8403 OZREN null NOC 15:12 8403 null SP SP 15:13 8403 DEJAN null SP 15:14 8403 null NOC NOC 15:40

Comment: so you will see it returned 2 rows but they are not consecutive

Comment: Hi Gordon again, unfortunately now is the result NULL but I know I do have two consecutive rows for specific ID which your previous SQL expression returned but this new unfortunately returns empty results :(

Comment: Hi Gordon, Edit 2 works thank you. One small question is it possible maybe to modify your SQL statement to start with SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ....and then your logic....... It is hard to explain but we are using some IBM application which send some emails where SQL expression is true. But all expressions are started with "select * from table where ..." and then we are putting the rest of the SQL statement? Is it possible maybe or not? Thank you

Comment: @Dejan . . . I don't understand what you mean.  Perhaps you should ask another question with a better description on the limitations of your interface.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I am just interested is it possible to change your query so it can start with "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ..." and then to modify your query so it can fit after the where clause